# How to expose Usercontrol Datagrid Events?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I am going to create a common User-Control which contains a data-grid. 
I could make data-grid object public and assign data-source and access other properties from outside where user-control is been used.

```
CommonControl.DataGrid.Datasource = dtStudents
```

But how can i let other developers to make events from outside by without changing the user-control coding. Then they can use that control datagrid as a normal grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as I know, it's not possible directly expose the events, unless you "forward the event out" (handle the event inside and raise it out).

but why not let developers just explicitly add the event handlers?  for example

> AddHandler commonCtrolInstrance.DataGrid.Click, AddressOf ClickEventHandlerMethod

and in order to let others to use it as a normal grid, at the property you created for DataGrid in CommonControl, do remember to put the attribute `<System.ComponentModel.Browsable(True)>`

another option is to directly create your custom common control by inheriting from DataGrid

Comment: It works thanks a lot. One more thing i want to clarify. Here i am using a Telerik RadGrid. In normal event handler it expects a e As Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridViewCellEventArgs but in the explicit handler e As System.EventArgs. Is it a problem of Telerik RadGrid

Comment: don't think it's a problem - normally all types of EventArgs are derived from System.EventArgs, though your explicit handler uses System.EvnetArgs as default parameter. and if you want to be sure, you could explicitly limit the e as your desired event Args type, so the warnings at your compiler for this case could go away.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to selectively expose few events, then you could create a `EventHandler` in your user control as below

```
private DataGridCommandEventHandler _dataGridEditCommand;
public event DataGridCommandEventHandler DataGridEditCommand
{
    add
    {
        _dataGridEditCommand += value;
    }
    remove
    {
        _dataGridEditCommand += value;
    }
}

protected void dgMain_EditCommand(object source, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (_dataGridEditCommand != null)
        _dataGridEditCommand(source, e);
}
```

People who uses the user control, in the aspx page, could then attach an event to it if they wish to (as below)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebUserControl1.DataGridEditCommand += WebUserControl1_DataGridEditCommand;
}

void WebUserControl1_DataGridEditCommand(object source, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
{
}
```